# Jenkins Gerrit polling fails: constantly triggering builds

Tags: git, jenkins

So we're using Gerrit Trigger (2.21.1) on our Jenkins CI build manager & using docker containers for the actual builds.

The issue that has recently popped up in some of our branches the Gerrit Repo polling is failing and causing it to "detect changes" every time, so it's constantly rebuilding despite no changes.

Checking the Gerrit Repo Polling Log for any of the affected jobs gives one of two outputs:

```
Gerrit Repo Polling Log

Started on Dec 20, 2016 11:31:01 AM
```

Which never seems to fill in, or:

```
Started on Dec 20, 2016 12:27:01 PM
Polling SCM changes on aosp-host
[workspace] $ repo init -u http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/git/project/platform/manifest.git -b branch -m branch.xml
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/jenkins/workspace/.repo/manifests.git'
fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/jenkins/workspace/.repo/manifests.git'
fatal: cannot obtain manifest http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/git/project/platform/manifest.git
Done. Took 1 min 19 sec
Changes found
```

The builds, which are triggered by this failure, use the same commands and work fine:

```
[workspace] $ repo init -u http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/git/project/platform/manifest.git -b branch -m branch.xml
```

Navigating to the manifest directory, we see the symptom:

```
jenkins@f052b3453d95:~/workspace/.repo$ ll 
total 32 
drwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins   180 Dec 20 11:08 ./ 
drwxrwxr-x 1 jenkins jenkins   778 Dec 20 11:07 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 20087 Dec 20 10:14 .repo_fetchtimes.json 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins jenkins    20 Dec 20 10:13 manifest.xml -> manifests/company.xml 
drwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins     8 Dec 16 17:33 manifests/ 
drwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins    50 Dec 16 17:33 manifests.git/ 
drwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins    28 Dec 16 17:43 project-objects/
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  7756 Dec 20 10:14 project.list 
drwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins   410 Dec 16 17:46 projects/
```

with

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins jenkins    20 Dec 20 10:13 manifest.xml -> manifests/company.xml
```

highlighted in red, because the associated `company.xml` is not found... so the Gerrit Log from above is accurate, it's failing to `init` properly. This is confirmed via a `repo status` in the main directory:

```
jenkins@f052b3453d95:~/workspace$ repo status
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jenkins/workspace/.repo/repo/main.py", line 531, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/jenkins/workspace/.repo/repo/main.py", line 507, in _Main
    result = repo._Run(argv) or 0
  File "/home/jenkins/workspace/.repo/repo/main.py", line 180, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "/home/jenkins/workspace/.repo/repo/subcmds/status.py", line 130, in Execute
    all_projects = self.GetProjects(args)
  File "/home/jenkins/workspace/.repo/repo/command.py", line 140, in GetProjects
    all_projects_list = manifest.projects
  File "/home/jenkins/workspace/.repo/repo/manifest_xml.py", line 350, in projects
    self._Load()
  File "/home/jenkins/workspace/.repo/repo/manifest_xml.py", line 407, in _Load
    self.manifestProject.worktree))
  File "/home/jenkins/workspace/.repo/repo/manifest_xml.py", line 443, in _ParseManifestXml
    root = xml.dom.minidom.parse(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1918, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 922, in parse
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/jenkins/workspace/.repo/manifest.xml'
```

The issue is, running `repo init -u <url> -m company.xml` via the command line works fine, and produces a valid repo.

Any insight one can offer for this issue?